# How portable is the `ps` command?

Tags: shell, unix, posix, portability, ps

I'm making a bash script and I'd like to make sure it's portable. For context, the command will be the part of [tmux-resurrect plugin](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tmux-resurrect).

I want to use this command: `ps -eo ppid,command`. Is that command portable?

I'd also be glad to hear how to check that myself. For example: maybe there's a service that can test commands on the large number of operating systems etc?

Comment: Well, you could sign up to some free shells from a list like http://shells.red-pill.eu/ to test… I don't know of any dedicated service for that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POSIX Standard is publicly available on the web. Yes, [ps](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ps.html) is one of the standardized utilities. If you stick to the standard options, you should be pretty portable.

Note however, that forcing some utilities to behave posixly correct, setting certain environment variables might be necessary. In particular, systems using the GNU utilities may need `POSIXLY_CORRECT=yes` or similar being set.